# In Java, is it safe to use "String ret = someString.split("\t")[0]"?

Tags: java

Is it safe to use `String ret = someString.split("\t")[0]` in Java?

I'm worried about `someString.split("\t")[0]` is temporary variable, so it might be recycled by GC.

Comment: Lots of people use split as array don't need to pass it into a array it's normal.

Comment: @SSpoke I'm used to C++ and always worried about those issues...

Comment: It will not get GC'ed. But you probably should check the array returned by `someString.split("\t")` unless you are absolutely sure that the array contains at least one element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's safe. And it doesn't matter that a "temporary" array is being created, you got the result you wanted and stored it in the local variable `ret`, so it won't go away. Garbage collection doesn't work like that, only the objects that are no longer referenced (say, by a local variable) are candidates for being garbage collected.

Comment: Yes, ret is referencing your result anyway.

Answer (score 2):

It is absolutely safe. When

```
someString.split("\t")
```

is executed, a reference to the object it returns is put on the stack. It is therefore reachable and cannot be GC'ed. The object can only be GC'ed after

```
someString.split("\t")[0]
                    // ^ array access
```

has been executed.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely.

If your application can use it, the garbage collector won't delete it<sup>1</sup>.

However there are a couple of unrelated edge-cases for your example:

- if `someString` is `null`, you will get a `NullPointerException`
- if `someString` is the empty string, then split will give you a zero length array, and that will result in an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

---

<sup>1 - The only exception is when something *outside* of the pure Java world does something really bad with references.  But when that happens, you've already got a corrupted heap, and a JVM crash is imminent.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

`String ret = someString.split("\t")[0];` will fail if `someString` is null, so no, it's not safe.

But if you know that `someString` is not null, then this is perfectly safe.  The garbage collector will never remove any values while it is still possible for your code to access them, so this is one thing you never need to worry about.